# PyTorch : How to apply the same random transformation to multiple image?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am writing a simple transformation for a dataset which contains many pairs of images. As a data augmentation, I want to apply some random transformation for each pair but the images in that pair should be transformed in the same way.
For example, given a pair of two images `A` and `B`, if `A` is flipped horizontally, `B` must be flipped horizontally as `A`. Then the next pair `C` and `D` should be differently transformed from `A` and `B` but `C` and `D` are transformed in the same way. I am trying that in the way below

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image

img_a = Image.open("sample_ajpg") # note that two images have the same size
img_b = Image.open("sample_b.png")
img_c, img_d = Image.open("sample_c.jpg"), Image.open("sample_d.png")

transform = transforms.RandomChoice(
    [transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(), 
     transforms.RandomVerticalFlip()]
)
random.seed(0)
display(transform(img_a))
display(transform(img_b))

random.seed(1)
display(transform(img_c))
display(transform(img_d))
```

Yet、 the above code does not choose the same transformation and as I tested, it is dependent on the number of times `transform` is called.

Is there any way to force `transforms.RandomChoice` to use the same transform when specified?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually a workaround is to apply the transform on the first image, retrieve the parameters of that transform, then apply with a deterministic transform with those parameters on the remaining images. However, here [`RandomChoice`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomChoice) does not provide an API to get the parameters of the applied transform since it involves a variable number of transforms.
In those cases, I usually implement an overwrite to the original function.

Looking at the [torchvision implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html#RandomChoice), it's as simple as:

```
class RandomChoice(RandomTransforms):
    def __call__(self, img):
        t = random.choice(self.transforms)
        return t(img)
```

Here are two possible solutions.

1. You can either sample from the transform list on `__init__` instead of on `__call__`:

   ```
   import random
   import torchvision.transforms as T

   class RandomChoice(torch.nn.Module):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.t = random.choice(self.transforms)

       def __call__(self, img):
           return self.t(img)
   ```

   So you can do:

   ```
   transform = RandomChoice([
        T.RandomHorizontalFlip(), 
        T.RandomVerticalFlip()
   ])
   display(transform(img_a)) # both img_a and img_b will
   display(transform(img_b)) # have the same transform

   transform = RandomChoice([
       T.RandomHorizontalFlip(), 
       T.RandomVerticalFlip()
   ])
   display(transform(img_c)) # both img_c and img_d will
   display(transform(img_d)) # have the same transform
   ```

---

2. Or better yet, transform the images in batch:

   ```
   import random
   import torchvision.transforms as T

   class RandomChoice(torch.nn.Module):
       def __init__(self, transforms):
          super().__init__()
          self.transforms = transforms

       def __call__(self, imgs):
           t = random.choice(self.transforms)
           return [t(img) for img in imgs]
   ```

   Which allows to do:

   ```
   transform = RandomChoice([
        T.RandomHorizontalFlip(), 
        T.RandomVerticalFlip()
   ])

   img_at, img_bt = transform([img_a, img_b])
   display(img_at) # both img_a and img_b will
   display(img_bt) # have the same transform

   img_ct, img_dt = transform([img_c, img_d])
   display(img_ct) # both img_c and img_d will
   display(img_dt) # have the same transform
   ```

Comment: Just to clarify, `transform = transforms.RandomChoice([` in your answer is actually `transform = RandomChoice([`,right?

Comment: Oups, sorry it should be `T.RandomChoice()` since I imported `torchvision.transforms` as `T`.

Comment: I agree transforming in a batch (where possible) seems like the best solution

Comment: I think it should be RandomChoice() not T.RandomChoice() otherwise it calls the RandomChoice class of torchvision.transforms. Also, when I tried this method with RandomRotate it doesn't work. because it only randomly chooses a transformation from the list of transformations you list, not within those transformations. For example if you have a pait of images that needs to be augmented the same way, this method unfortunately doesn't work because they still might be transformed by random degrees.

Answer (score 4):

I realize the OP requested a solution using `torchvision` and I think @Ivan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448680/7446465) does a good job addressing this.

However, for those not tied to a specific augmentation library, I wanted to point out that Albumentations appears to handle these kind of situations nicely in a [native fashion](https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/example_multi_target/) by allowing the user to pass multiple source images, boxes, etc into the same transform. The return is structured as a dict

```py
import albumentations as A

transform = A.Compose(
    transforms=[
        A.VerticalFlip(p=0.5),
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5)],
    additional_targets={'image0': 'image', 'image1': 'image'}
)
transformed = transform(image=image, image0=image0, image1=image1)
```

Now you can access `transformed['image0']`, `transformed['image1']`, etc and all of them will have random parameters applied

Comment: What is the torchvision.transforms equivalent of this?

Comment: I don't know of a torchvision equivalent which was why I suggest Albumentations

Answer (score 4):

Referencing [Random transforms for both input and target?](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/9#issuecomment-789308878) I think this is probably the cleanest way to do it. Save the random state before applying any transformation and the just restore it for each consequent call

```py
t = transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=360)
state = torch.get_rng_state()
x = t(x)
torch.set_rng_state(state)
y = t(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, take the randomization part out of PyTorch into an `if` statement.
Below code uses `vflip`. Similarly for horizontal or other transforms.

```
import random
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF

if random.random() > 0.5:
    image = TF.vflip(image)
    mask  = TF.vflip(mask)
```

This issue has been discussed in PyTorch [forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torchvision-transfors-how-to-perform-identical-transform-on-both-image-and-target/10606). Several solutions' pros and cons were discussed on the official GitHub repository [page](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/9).
PyTorch maintainers have suggested this simple approach.

Do not use `torchvision.transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(p=1)`. Use `torchvision.transforms.functional.vflip`

Functional transforms give you fine-grained control of the transformation pipeline. As opposed to the transformations above, functional transforms don’t contain a random number generator for their parameters. That means you have to specify/generate all parameters, but you can reuse the functional transform.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the suggestion. I've added explanation :-)

Comment: This answer is underrated. Why change the whole class, if you can just use a random number? This also works for things such as random cropping: Simply use `torchvision.transforms.crop()` with random ints for the `top` and `left` params (make sure for them to be within `[0,orig_size-target_size[`).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a function to fix the random output.
maybe try a different logic, like creating the randomization yourself to be able to reuse the same transformation.
logic:

- generate a random number
- based on the number apply a transformation on both images
- generate another random number
- do the same for the other two images
  try this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image

img_a = Image.open("sample_ajpg") # note that two images have the same size
img_b = Image.open("sample_b.png")
img_c, img_d = Image.open("sample_c.jpg"), Image.open("sample_d.png")

if random.random() > 0.5:
        image_a_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.vflip(img_a)
        image_b_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.vflip(img_b)
else:
    image_a_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.hflip(img_a)
    image_b_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.hflip(img_b)

if random.random() > 0.5:
        image_c_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.vflip(img_c)
        image_d_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.vflip(img_d)
else:
    image_c_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.hflip(img_c)
    image_d_flipped = transforms.functional_pil.hflip(img_d)
    
display(image_a_flipped)
display(image_b_flipped)

display(image_c_flipped)
display(image_d_flipped)
```